# Getting "No overload matches this call" error while converting code to TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm new with TypeScript, I have converted all my code (React Hooks) into TypeScript except for this one thing where I get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.

  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; error?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "outlined" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & CommonProps & Pick): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: Element; className: string; htmlFor: string; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; className: string; htmlFor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; color?
```

The issue is coming from here:

```js
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  TextField,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Select,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import { Trans } from "react-i18next";

interface ConnectedLinkProps {
  onSubmit: string;
  classes: {
    formControl: string;
  };
}


<FormControl className={classes.formControl} htmlFor="source">
  <TextField
    id="source"
    disabled={true}
    value={linkSettings.source}
    label={<Trans i18nKey="form.linkForm.sourceNode">Source Node</Trans>}
  />
</FormControl>;
```

The whole first line which is 'FormControl line' is red.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i added more needed code and also imports, could you help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The error should go away if you remove the props from the `FormControl` component.

```js
<FormControl>
  <TextField
    id="source"
    disabled={true}
    value="Something"
    label={<Trans i18nKey="form.linkForm.sourceNode">Source Node</Trans>}
  />
</FormControl>
```

The [FormControl](https://mui.com/api/form-control/) component doesn't support the `className` or `htmlFor` prop.

[Link to a forked example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-samplecode-forked-7bseo?file=/src/i18nextTest.tsx:258-478).

The working example of the shared code will be something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  TextField,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Select,
  InputLabel
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import { Trans } from "react-i18next";

interface ConnectedLinkProps {
  onSubmit: string;
  classes: {
    formControl: string;
  };
}

const App: React.FC<ConnectedLinkProps> = ({ onSubmit, classes }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="source">Something</InputLabel>
        <TextField
          id="source"
          disabled={true}
          value="Something"
          label={<Trans i18nKey="form.linkForm.sourceNode">Source Node</Trans>}
          className={classes?.formControl}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: but those props i need and it is working with 'js' but when converting to 'tsx' i get that error

Comment: In that case, it should be something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-samplecode-forked-s85w9?file=/src/i18nextTest.tsx:280-635). It will work in JS as JS isn't checking for the appropriate types from the MUI library.

Comment: could you possibly give working example using my code, so i can accept ?

Comment: how about 'htmlFor="id"' should i add it to 'TextField' ?

Comment: `htmlFor` is available only on the `InputLabel` component.

Comment: so that code should work exactly as my code ?

Comment: If the add the `htmlFor` prop to the `InputLabel` component, then it should work fine.

Comment: <InputLabel htmlFor="id">Something</InputLabel>
?

Comment: @walee Yes. It is in the code that I shared.

Comment: yes but you have 'source' in it and also TextField id has 'source' i thought it should be same : )

Comment: Sorry about that confusion :)